# To switch between two video files in Qt or opencv python -seamlessly

Tags: qt, opencv, pyqt, video-player

Currently i'm using opencv (have an option to use QT as well) to play a video file (player) in full screen mode. My requirement is when i'm playing videofile-1 there could a request to play video file-2 and i need to switch to video file-2 seamlessly. Is it possible to do this in opencv or QT ?  I know we can do this using RTSP or HTTP streaming.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV uses `cv2.VideoCapture()` to read from videofile and `cv2.imshow()` to project image/video to display. What are you doing between those you it is your choice, so answering your question I guess it's possible.